# Python:division vs. shift

Tags: python

In python, there are

`division (//, /) and shift (>>, <<).`

1. In the performance matter, shift operator is more beneficial?!
2. Is there any benefits using shift rather than division operator?!

Comment: Sometimes you are manipulating bits and want a shift rather than a division, e.g. if you want to compactly store a lot of booleans: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After measurement using the following code, the shift seems to be a bit slower but it is not significant and it is on my computer, your results may differ.

I got the following answer:

```
It took 42.1938125s for division by 2
It took 43.217766499999996s for integer division by 2
It took 47.926054599999986s for shift by 1
It took 41.82601500000001s for division by 4
It took 43.20513730000002s for integer division by 4
It took 48.33005560000004s for shift by 2
```

```py
import timeit
import random

random.seed(42)
DATA = [random.randint(0,10000) for _ in range(400)]

def measure(func, name):
    time = timeit.timeit(lambda: [func(val) for val in DATA], number=1000000)
    print(f"It took {time}s for {name}")

measure(lambda x:x / 2, "division by 2")
measure(lambda x:x // 2, "integer division by 2")
measure(lambda x:x >> 1, "shift by 1")
measure(lambda x:x / 4, "division by 4")
measure(lambda x:x // 4, "integer division by 4")
measure(lambda x:x >> 2, "shift by 2")
```